SystemError: NFIUnsatisfiedLinkError: Dynamic loading not supported
i tried to use graalpy in a static-linked native-image on aarch64 linux platform,
after all the obstacles,i finally managed to generate an executable file.
it accept a file path of a python script and runs in graalpy.
core code is:
    @GetMapping("/eval")
    public void eval(@RequestParam("path") String path) {
        try (var context = GraalPyResources.createContext()) {
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(path));
            String sourceString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println("source code is:\n" + sourceString);
            Source source = Source.create("python", sourceString);
            context.eval(source);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


more importantly,the build.gradle file is as follows
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.4.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.7'
    id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.10.4'
    id "org.graalvm.python" version "24.1.1"
}

group = 'com.chaney.infra'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(23)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

graalPy {
    packages = ["numpy==1.24.3","termcolor==2.2"]
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.graalvm.polyglot:polyglot:24.1.1'
    runtimeOnly 'org.graalvm.polyglot:llvm:24.1.1'
    implementation 'org.graalvm.polyglot:python:24.1.1'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

def projectName = "graalpy"

graalvmNative {
    binaries {
        main {
            imageName.set(projectName)
            sharedLibrary = false

            buildArgs.add('--verbose')
            buildArgs.add('--no-fallback')
            buildArgs.add('--static')
            buildArgs.add('--libc=musl')

            buildArgs.add('--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED')
            buildArgs.add('--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED')
            buildArgs.add('--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED')
            buildArgs.add('-H:+CopyLanguageResources')
            buildArgs.add('--gc=serial')
            buildArgs.add('-O1')
        }
    }
}


it can run simple python code, but when it comes to numpy,an error occures.
source code is:
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ZEROS = np.zeros(5)
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    print(a)
    print(ZEROS)

below is the error stack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Unnamed", line 1, in <module>
  File "/graalpy_vfs/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
  File "/graalpy_vfs/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__config__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
  File "/graalpy_vfs/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/graalpy_vfs/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/graalpy_vfs/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 8, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
SystemError: NFIUnsatisfiedLinkError: Dynamic loading not supported
2024-12-23T07:26:49.931Z ERROR 242964 --- [graalPy] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException] with root cause

org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: null
    at org.graalvm.polyglot/org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:402) ~[na:na]
    at com.chaney.infra.graalpy.endpoint.DemoController.eval(DemoController.java:25) ~[graalpy:na]
    at java.base@23.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[graalpy:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:257) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:986) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1088) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:978) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[graalpy:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[graalpy:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[graalpy:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[graalpy:6.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483) ~[graalpy:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[graalpy:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:397) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[graalpy:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:905) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[graalpy:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@23.0.1/java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1588) ~[graalpy:na]
    at java.base@23.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1575) ~[graalpy:na]
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:832) ~[graalpy:na]
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:808) ~[graalpy:na]

I also created this GitHub repository to make reproducing this issue easier:
https://github.com/buuuuuuug/graalpy
Follow the README.md file will probably lead to the same error here.

You could maybe try adding --language:python to the native-image arguments. I don't think that's necessary any more but it might be worth trying.
